# Reading HTML Contents Into Javascript String

Tags: javascript

I have been using

```
$autoComplete = file_get_contents("stackoverflow.com");
```

When using PHP, but I now need a Javascript equivalent. Is there one..

I need to read a txt file that is accessed via URL..

I obviously have been googling, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be great..

Comment: If "nothing seems to work", it sounds like you actually found, and then tried, several things. That's great! But please [remember to show/tell us](/help/how-to-ask) _what_ you tried, so we can tell whether you're actually going down the right road or whether you've completely misunderstood how JS works.

Answer (score -3):

This is what you need: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Something like:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: why show jQuery when the JS Fetch API is a perfectly fine, modern bit of JS on every browser?

Comment: The appropriate thing to do here, as a 6K user, is to [VTC](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as a duplicate here not answer

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: How could I access/display that jQuery - say in an alert box.